# DataTable.Expression Method does not use C# integer division

Tags: c#, datatable

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("", typeof(double));
dataTable.Columns[0].Expression = "(1/3)*3000.00";
DataRow r = dataTable.NewRow();
dataTable.Rows.Add(r);
int result = dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

The computed `result` is 1000, but I expected 0, since `1/3` = 0 and `(0)*3000.00` = 0.

Comment: There is a problem with basic arithmetic. What's this: `1/3==>0`?

Comment: @oleksii I guess, OP expects it should be performed as integer arithmetic and give the result 0.

Comment: Why do you expect that the DataColumn expression calculates by using integer division? I assume that `System.Double` is used internally. Btw, integer division is not even .NET specific since VB.NET also calculate `1/3=0.33333333333333331`

Comment: @TimSchmelter what is the difference between standart expressions and DataTable expressions ? [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) doesn't state anything different it says: `Integer literals [+-]?[0-9]+ are treated as System.Int32, System.Int64 or System.Double. ...`  so in this case 1 and 3 should be treated as `Int32` and  `1/3` should be performed using integer division.

Comment: @Selman22: maybe it's a lack in the documentation. Since the expression syntax must also work implicitly(with tables that have a computed column) and it must work between different languages, i assume that they have decided to use the more natural division that is the VB.NET way without truncating the decimal place. So i assume that the `Eval` method which detects the types uses `System.Double` if there is a division even if the literals are `System.Int32`. The source is not that simple: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/Filter/FunctionNode.cs#ff4072c8661c4cc3

Answer (score 1):

Integer division is not taking place when you have specified column type as `double`:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
  dt.Columns.Add("X", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Y", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("R", typeof(int), "X/Y");
  dt.Columns.Add("", typeof(double), "R*3000.00");
  dt.Columns.Add("test", typeof(double), "(1/3)*3000.00");
  DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
  r["X"] = 1;
  r["Y"] = 3;
  dt.Rows.Add(r);
  int i = (int)dt.Rows[0]["R"];     //return 0
  double d = (double)dt.Rows[0][3]; //return 0.0
  double d1 = (double)dt.Rows[0]["test"]; //return 1000.0
```

Answer (score -1):

`(1/3)*3000.00 = 1000.00`

If you use the following, you get the result you expect:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns[0].Expression = "(1/3)*1.00";
DataRow r = dataTable.NewRow();
dataTable.Rows.Add(r);
int result = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Note that the result of the calculation `(1/3)*1.00` = 0.3333..., and when the *result* is converted to an `int` it becomes `0`.

The same thing with a `double` results in 0.3333...

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("", typeof(double));
dataTable.Columns[0].Expression = "(1/3)*1.00";
DataRow r = dataTable.NewRow();
dataTable.Rows.Add(r);
double result = (double)dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: But OP wants to enforce integer division for `1/3` which gives `0`

Comment: The expression is `(1/3)*3000.00` and one third of `3000.00` is `1000.00`; if it was based on integers, it would be on the result of the calculation, not the individual parts of the expression. Finally, the column data type is a `double` so I would expect a result of data type `double` to be returned.